# Python: Is there a way to cause all references to an object to refer to another?

Tags: python

For example (greatly simplified from the actual usage):

I have a list of 10,000 references to one of 3 objects:

```
a,b,c = {'font-size':1},{'font-size':2},{'font-size':2.3}`
styles = [a,b,c,a,a,a,a,a,b,......] #10,000
```

This saves me the memory of creating a new dict for each of the 10000 indexes, since they all fall into one of three values (in reality, there are hundreds).

Now I decide that font-size must be an int, so I round `c` to `{'font-size':2}`. But I want all `c` to become `b`, since they are now one and the same.

Is there a way (short of going thorough the list and comparing every value and replacing it if needed, which I am aware of, but slow if I have to do it again & again for many objects) to just make all references to `c` refer to `b`? I know python keeps a list of such references for garbage cleanup. Or maybe the object referenced by `c` can be made in turn to reference `b` automatically?

Edit: I appreciate the suggested workarounds, but as stated in the comments, the workarounds all leave me with issues I am looking to reduce (memory consumption or time consumption) by finding an answer to the question as asked (changing the reference through pythons list of references or somehow redirecting the reference internally in python).

Comment: does `c=b` make any help?

Comment: No, since in `styles` it would still refer to `c`, i.e. `styles[2] is b == False`

Comment: To my knowledge, what you're asking for is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

How about using indexes for `styles`:

```
template = a, b, c = {'font-size':1},{'font-size':2},{'font-size':2.3}`
#styles = [a,b,c,a,a,a,a,a,b,......]
styles  = [0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,......]

c['font-size'] = 2
# OR  template[2]['font-size'] = 2
# OR  template[2] = template[1]
```

Downside:

Additional dereference is needed to access actual value: `template[styles[i]]` instead of `styles[i]`

Comment: I like the approach `# OR  template[2] = template[1]` but often times I also need to go through `styles` and know whether each adjacent style is the same as the previous, which will get slow if (as you pointed out) I have to dereference 2 to 1 each time.

Comment: @Jeff, How about `styles = [1 if i == 2 else i for i in styles]` or `styles[:] = [1 if i == 2 else i for i in styles]` , and only check indexes, not the content ?

Comment: Probably alot faster then my fallback `for` loop, since using list comprehension instead. (and can drop using indexes and '==' for: `styles = [b if i is c else i for i in styles]`,) I'll still hold out for another answer that doesn't involve rewriting the entire list though.

Answer (score 0):

Reassign the value of c and then reassign the value of styles

```
c = b
styles = [a,b,c,a,a,a,a,a,b,......] #10,000
```

Then c will refer to b. This is one solution that I could think of

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [2,3,4]
>>> c = [a,b]
>>> b = a
>>> c[1]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [a,b]
>>> c[1]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: As mentioned, short of going through styles and comparing every value, I no longer know how to assign styles. It was assigned values at some earlier point, somewhere else in the program, and now needs to be changed. I can't just do `styles=[.....]`

Comment: @Jeff: If the styles was assigned in some function, you can call the function again maybe

Comment: `c = [a,b]` (the second to the last statement) ?

Comment: @Aswin Murugesh: Nope, not in my situation. It is setup originally by a rather slow function, and then modified over time by user input...

Comment: @falsetru: Ya. Reassigning c. That is what my answer says

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand but if you only have the three styles and you want to replace every occurrence of b in styles with c, you can do:

```
a,b,c = {'font-size':1},{'font-size':2},{'font-size':2.3}
styles = [a,b,c,a,a,a,a,a,b,c,a]
for n,i in enumerate(styles):
  if i==b:
    styles[n]=c
print styles

>>>[{'font-size': 1}, {'font-size': 2.3}, {'font-size': 2.3}, ...
```

Comment: As stated, `short of going thorough the list and comparing every value and replacing it if needed, which I am aware of, but slow if I have to do it again & again for many objects`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
a, b, c = the_values = [{'font-size': 1}, {'font-size': 2}, {'font-size': 2.3}]
styles = [a, b, c, a, a, a, c, a, a, b, b, c]
# and now:
c['font-size'] = 2
the_values_immutable = [tuple(d.items()) for d in the_values]
reduced = set(the_values_immutable)
mapping = { itmtup: dict(itmtup) for itmtup in reduced }
new_styles = [mapping[tuple(d.items())] for d in styles]
```

This creates a list of tuples representing each dict. Then it reduces it by means of set arithmetics.

The result is a list of styles with completely new objects.

If you prefer to have some of the old items retained for any reasons, you'd better replace

```
mapping = { itmtup: dict(itmtup) for itmtup in reduced }
```

for something which looks up each of the items in the old `the_values` list.

If you have to do that quite often and want to reduce it as often as you need, you should add one level of indirection instead.

See [falsetru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20592527/296974) in this case.

Comment: Is this any faster than using a `for` loop (or falsetru's suggestion `styles = [b if i is c else i for i in styles]`? Edit: I think your edit ("one level of indirection...") is the same as his answer, if I understood correctly?, in which case see my first comment on his answer .

Comment: @Jeff It depends on how often you do that. Does it really hurt if you have two objects which have the same content? Maybe you should stick with one style dict for each text region which is conceptually the same. And if two styles physically become the same, they stay distict in a logical way and can be changed again together if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since`c`is a container, you could empty it and then copy the items from`b`into it. This would likely be less work than potentially changing up to 10,000 entries in`styles`.

```
a,b,c = {'font-size':1},{'font-size':2},{'font-size':2.3}
styles = [a,b,c,a,a,a,a,a,b,]

c.clear()
for k in b:
    c[k] = b[k]

print styles
```

Output:

```
[{'font-size': 1}, {'font-size': 2}, {'font-size': 2}, {'font-size': 1},
 {'font-size': 1}, {'font-size': 1}, {'font-size': 1}, {'font-size': 1},
 {'font-size': 2}]
```

Comment: Since I will be doing it many, many times, with large objects, and as stated I am looking to conserve memory, I do not want to have multitudes of containers that are exactly the same. Also, this is a workaround, which I appreciate, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question and is a workaround. However, it doesn't create any more containers -- there's never more than the three in existence. It just _changes_ the contents of one of them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the context. You are correct, but I have far more and larger containers, and am constantly creating new ones (for example) {font-size:3} and then changing them *also* to font-size:2, once again creating a new copy of the same thing. It also just occurred to me, I will often only want to change *some* of the font-size:2 to 3, so I can't just replace the contents.

Comment: As I said this doesn't create additional containers. It's also possible to selectively update the contents of `c` if you wish. The bottomline is that it _is_ very memory-efficient.